# Convert GeoTIFF DEM to DTED level 2 (.dt2) without modifying bounds

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, dted

I tried converting GeoTIFF DEM to DTED using GDAL with following command

```
gdal_translate -of DTED -outsize 1201 1201 -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 -co LEVEL=2 somefile.tif somefile.dt2
```

It gives a warning "The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries". The resulting dt2 file bounds are getting changed.

Comment: The DTED format has a very rigid specification with respect to bounds and coordinate system, there's a table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTED showing the allowed cell sizes in arcseconds. If want you can find the original military spec for DTED it's a seriously long read, link in the driver docs https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/dted.html. GDAL is just following the specification.

Comment: DTED is a military specification. They have hardware engineered to work with it, so playing fast and loose with the spec is not going to fly (potentially literally).